# Transform xml to xml using XSLT - Advices

Tags: c#, xml, xslt

I have one `XML` file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?>
<Cars>
    <Car>
        <Color>Blue</Color>
        <Model>Car2</Model>
        <Year>1988</Year>
        <Speed>250</Speed>
    </Car>
    <Car>
        <Color>Blue</Color>
        <Model>Car2</Model>
        <Year>1988</Year>
        <Speed>250</Speed>
    </Car>
</Cars>
```

I want to transform this using `XSLT` for have :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?>
<vehicles>
    <vehicle>
        <vehicleColor>Blue</vehicleColor>
        <vehicleModel>Car2</vehicleModel>
        <vehicleYear>1988</vehicleYear>
        <vehicleSpeed>250</vehicleSpeed>
    </vehicle>
    <vehicle>
        <vehicleColor>Blue</vehicleColor>
        <vehicleModel>Car2</vehicleModel>
        <vehicleYear>1988</vehicleYear>
        <vehicleSpeed>250</vehicleSpeed>
    </vehicle>
</vehicles>
```

My `XSLT` File :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:template match="/">

        <vehicles>
            <xsl:for-each select="Cars/Car">

                <vehicle>
                    <vehicleColor><xsl:value-of select="Color"/></vehicleColor>
                    <vehicleModel><xsl:value-of select="Model"/></vehicleModel>
                    <vehicleYear><xsl:value-of select="Year"/></vehicleYear>
                    <vehicleSpeed><xsl:value-of select="Speed"/></vehicleSpeed>
                </vehicle>

            </xsl:for-each>
        </vehicles>

    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

It work but I want to know if my `XSLT` file is correct and if no, I want advices.

Also, in my output file generated with `XSLT`, I have not the `XML` header. Why ?

Comment: *It work but I want to know if my XSLT file is correct*...if it worked with no errors XSLT should be correct.

Comment: By _"it work....I want advices"_ do you mean _can your XSLT be **optimised**?_

Comment: @MickyD Yes, I'm really beginner in transforming XML file

Comment: Might be better to ask this type of question on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Azerty123 Is this question not answered?

Answer (score 0):

Your XSLT is just fine.  I think the best way to answer this question for the benefit of helping people study XSLT is to go through your tags and explain why they work correctly.  First, you need to add the XSL stylesheet and namespace, as you've done here:

`<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">`
`<xsl:template match ='/'>` is boilerplate.  If you did not have it, the output would be incorrect.

The `<xsl:for-each select="Cars/Car">` calls each element of the XML DOM that matches that tag specified by `select =`.

Next, you used all your literal tags to directly change the names of tags in your output file.  A tag is literal in the sense that XSLT will just drop it into your output.  The `<xsl:value-of select = someString>` tag writes the value of the tag in the original file specified by someString.  If you wanted to write an attribute, you would need an @ symbol at the first position of the string. Regardless of what data you had started with, your output file would contain the correct results.  If you are having doubts, because, as you say, you are just learning XSLT, getting a trial version of XMLSpy is a great way of validating your XSLT files to verify they are doing what you want them to.

Comment: Thank's for your answer. Is it better to use `<xsl:element name="">` for define all name of my futur nodes ?

Comment: @Azerty123 Use `xsl:element` when you need to calculate the name. Otherwise use a literal result element.

Answer (score 0):

> I have not the XML header.

The XML declaration is optional. Most XSLT processor will include it, unless you explicitly omit it. If your processor doesn't, try adding:

```
<xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="no"/>
```

to the top level of your stysleheet.

---

> I want to know if my XSLT file is correct

There is nothing wrong with your stylesheet.

However, if you are really only prepending "vehicle" to the names of the elements, you could do it all at once:

```
<xsl:template match="/Cars">
    <vehicles>
        <xsl:for-each select="Car">
            <vehicle>
                <xsl:for-each select="*">
                    <xsl:element name="vehicle{name()}">
                        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                    </xsl:element>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </vehicle>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </vehicles>
</xsl:template>
```